# how to get timezone offset value

Tags: javascript

My requirement is , i need to convert the time zone value to offset value 
for ex.. Asia/Dubai to +4 .. 
consider am intializing date in js.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

and it is possible to set the time zone and get the offset..

```
currentDate.setTimezone("Asia/Dubai");
var offsetValue=currentDate.getTimezoneOffset();

alert('offsetValue---'+offsetValue);
```

its not working.. page error at set time zone.. is there any other way to get the offet value?
Need to consider DST too..

Comment: What's your opinion regarding daylight savings time?

Comment: use timezone-js. this will make your work simpler ..

Comment: can u share me that? timezone.js

Comment: Best link on SO for TimeZone and daylight saving time:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid jquery statement

```
currentDate.setTimezone("Asia/Dubai");
```

just remove this line and you'll get the timezone offset.

Comment: hi my query is i need to convert asia/dubai to +4... please read the first line of the description

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object doesn't know a `setTimezone` method. If you want to set a `Date` to the 'Asia/Dubai' timezone, this could be a way:

```
var regionalDate = new Date;
regionalDate.setHours(regionalDate.getUTCHours()+4); //=> set to UTC+4
```

Comment: hi my query is i need to convert asia/dubai to +4..please read the first line of the description

Comment: Well, you'll have to think of something yourself for such a conversion. There's no miraculous native timezoneconverter in javascript. It could be as easy as assigning a value to a variable called 'Dubai' (`var Dubai = 4`), or creating an object for different timezones (`var zones = {Asia: { Dubai:4, Brunei:8, Mumbai: 5.5 }, Europe: {Amsterdam: {summer:2; winter:1} }`) etc. It's up to you. See also: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/

Comment: @mnp: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/check-if-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-it-is-for-how-many-hours